Which is the default butter in the US? salted or unsalted?
Whenever I watch culinary videos, every time butter is involved, it is referred as unsalted butter.
This is such a rule that I came to wonder wheather salted butter is the norm (or "default") in the US?
We do have salted butter in France (it however comes from abroad - from Brittany :)) but it is very explicitly stated when you need to use it, which is far, far, faaaar less common than normal butter.

Most people who don't cook probably don't even realize there's a difference.  The big issue is that every brand uses a different amount of salt, so for recipes that you actually care about consistency (like baking, where you can't sample as you go), it's safer to standardize on unsalted butter and then add salt.

Most people who don't cook probably don't even realize there's a difference I am not sure I understand. Here in France it is difficult to miss the fact that one is eating salted butter (because it is very salted - it is even called demi-sel in France, which means "half salt", but that thankfully does not reflect the real amount :) It is 0.5 to 3% salt. And I just learned  reading Wikipedia that we also have "salted butter" (beurre salé) which I never seen in my life (it seems to exist in Brittany)

there are a LOT of people in the US who are completely clueless when it comes to cooking, as they never learned.  Looking at comments on recipe sites makes it pretty obvious (complaining about a recipe, while mentioning the changes they made).  I know adults who think a "clove" of garlic is the full bulb or that scallions and shallots are the same thing.    You have to make sure you are VERY specific when giving recipes.  Even a term like 'shelled nuts' can be confusing because people think it means 'nuts in the shell' instead of 'nuts that have been de-shelled'

Side remark: you don't have to go that far away, "normal" butter is salted in Scandinavian countries already, and you have to look for the specific unsalted one if you want to eat it with jam, marmalade, and co. Or just don't care: Norwegians often eat sweet rice porridge with a spoonful of salted butter.

@WoJ it's "demi-sel" as in half the salt of buerre salé. Are you perhaps in a part of France that uses olive oil rather than butter traditionally? Because I've mostly visited northern France and both salé and demi-sel are common in multiple brands in most supermarkets

I think the 'english' equivilent of demi sel would be 'slightly salted'

Here (Germany) the default is unsalted butter (though one can buy salted butter like garlic/spiced butter), and the more usual distinction is cultured or not. I long ago went to Canada for a research stay and made a German-style crumble cake for the "first day" coffee break and didn't realize that the butter I bought was salted until I tasted the mixture... However, my landlady recommended to proceed since North Americans are accustomed to much salt. In the end I explained to the colleagues, who tried and liked the taste. (That may be: I know I'm on the low salt side for Germans)

@ChrisH I am from around Paris, so butter is the fat of choice (at least traditionally). When you go to a typical supermarket, you will hardly find beurre salé: https://www.auchan.fr/oeufs-produits-laitiers/cremerie-oeufs-laits/beurres/ca-n010105?page=1 I have never seen any (but I have never looked for any either - though I would have at least noticed after 50 years :)) Wherever I search for beurre salé it gives me demi-sel (just tried at Carrefour as well)

@tevemadar Scandinavians don’t generally buy different butter to use with jam or marmelade – salted butter still works fine for that. Note, however, that Scandinavian butter is almost always cultured, with a salt content of around 1%, whereas North American butter is most frequently uncultured, with a salt content of 2–4%, so it tends to be significantly more salty than Scandinavian butter.

@WoJ I'm surprised, because without refrigeration you'd need to use unsalted butter the day you make it or throw it away. Even in the fridge, it spoils in 1-2 weeks. Salted butter will survive a week out of the fridge, and can easily last a month or two in the fridge. In a warmer country like France, this seems strange. But maybe it's just about the flavour, and not about how long it can survive. Or possibly it's a change since fridges became available?

@Graham as far back as I can remember (the 80's), butter was always kept in the fridge. We have these nice glass containers for it, but they also went to the fridge. In contrast, when I visited friends in Poland, they would often keep the butter (unslated as well) outside, covered with water.

@WoJ I keep my butter in the fridge, but mostly because I live in a desert where it is hot all summer, and I don't want to pay for the AC more than I have to---if I were to keep butter on the counter, it would make a sloppy mess.

@Graham: unsalted butter keeps just fine in the fridge for months. Unrefrigerated (in a butter dish on the counter), it would last at least two weeks, except that it tends to get consumed way before then. "Use unsalted butter the day you make it or throw it away" is utter and complete nonsense.

@Marti I use half salted and half unsalted butter for most recipes. Refrigerated, it is rancid and entirely unusable within 2 weeks. Perhaps you are freezing yours? Normally I'd eat salted butter; but when I have accidentally left a pat of unsalted butter out of the fridge,  it was rancid after 2 days. You'll understand it's not an experiment I do repeatedly, for that reason.

@WoJ perhaps salted butter is more of a Breton/Normand thing then; that's where I've been the most. While I've been in and near Paris often enough only one of those trips could have involved a supermarket

@Graham I have kept unsalted butter in the fridge for a few weeks and it never went bad. I usually keep it at least 2 weeks if not more. I just checked the butter I bought last week - it is good until 2025-02-08. This is the "best before date", you can add three weeks or so to this.

@ChrisH yes, for sure (I mentioned this in my question when mentioning provenance)

@Graham Unsalted, uncultured butter will generally not last nearly as long as unsalted, cultured butter. French butter is generally unsalted but cultured, while at least the salted butter sold in the UK and North America tends to be uncultured, and I suspect the unsalted variants sold there may also be, like industry-used butter (for things like baking and confectionery at least) often is. So your experience may reflect uncultured butter, while WoJ’s reflects cultured butter.

If a US or Canadian recipe just says "butter" they mean salted butter. It keeps much longer than unsalted butter. That's why the recipe people say "unsalted butter" - because it's not the cultural default, even if it may be the butter they happen to prefer in all their recipes.
You can add salt to unsalted butter (about 1/4 tsp of salt per half cup of butter) if your recipe calls for salted and you don't have it. If the recipe calls for unsalted and you only have salted, there may be some salt elsewhere in the recipe that you can reduce by that amount.

The comments here are interesting, but they have gotten unwieldy. I have moved the conversation to chat.

@Jolenealaska: is there a link to said chat?

Because I am a math guy, and this question seems to admit a data-driven answer, a bit of Googling reveals the following:

According to a 2018 article in the Washington Post,

...since 2012, 77 percent of the butter sold in America has been salted and 23 percent unsalted. Tom Balmer, executive director of the American Butter Institute, quoted similar figures, but said that when it comes to bulk sales, unsalted butter sells more.


Ken Research (an organization I have never heard of before, but poking around their site makes them seem trustworthy on this issue) displays a chart showing that salted butter sales make up a near majority of the butter market in the US, with unsalted, whipped, and clarified butter filling out the rest of the market.  It appears that these numbers are in dollars spent (rather than amount bought), and more processed products (like whipped and clarified butter) are likely more expensive, but salted and unsalted butter are similar in cost, so the relative sales of the two likely represent similar quantities of butter.  From the article, it looks like salted butter outsells unsalted butter by a factor of two or three to one (this is consistent with the Washington Post article).
Quoting the article:

The USA Butter Market is segmented by product type into salted butter, unsalted butter, whipped butter, and clarified butter. Among these, salted butter dominates the market due to its long-standing popularity among consumers and its extended shelf life, which makes it a preferred choice in household kitchens. Additionally, salted butter is widely used in foodservice industries for cooking and baking purposes, further driving its dominance.


There are a number of other market research sites which seem to give a similar impression:  salted butter is more popular in the US, by a factor of (perhaps) three to one (i.e. 75%ish of the market is salted, 25%ish is unsalted).


Beyond that, I am finding it surprisingly difficult to find reliable or trustworthy information about this---kind of makes me with that I knew a grad student or two at Iowa State or Texas A&M. :)
The conclusion I would draw from the above is that, while salted butter probably outsells unsalted butter by a fair margin, the margin is not enough to conclude that salted butter is the "default", particularly in light of confounding factors like the use of salted butter in food production.  Because both salted and unsalted are commonly available, and because it can make a difference in a recipe, most authors will specify.

That makes sense.  People shopping at grocery stores favor salted butter, while the people buying the bulk stuff (likely restaurants and bakeries) are more likely to go for unsalted.  So professionals are more likely to be using unsalted, which is it the main type being purchased by households and needs to be specifically called out

@Joe I'm not sure that the data are fine grained enough to make that conclusion.  My interpretation is that both quantities are sold in the US, in numbers which are close enough to each other that recipes feel the need to specify.  Anecdotally, my grocery store devotes about the same amount of shelf space to salted and unsalted butter (this representing the "household" market).

Salted and unsalted butter are side by side on the shelves, and different people have different preferences. A lot of people like the extra flavor salt provides, and so prefer salted butter for spreading on bread. If you want to control just how much salt is in a recipe, unsalted butter is better so you can add just the amount you want. But if someone just asks for butter, you should probably ask if they care which kind. They may even want spreadable "butter" in a tub.

I agree, it's really about context. If someone asks for butter so that they can make bread, they want unsalted. If someone asks for butter so that they can eat bread, they want salted.

They may even want spreadable "butter" in a tub OK, we went too far here :)

@WoJ Just wait until you send someone to the store to get butter, and they come back with a tub of I Can't Belive It's Not Butter™.

My neighbors referred to Country Crock as "tub butter".  Growing up and first starting out on my own, margarine in tubs was not only convenient it meant that you also had a reusable container

@XanderHenderson TBH we also have margarine. I tried it once during COVID when the "thing to look of the day" was butter (before it was pasta and like in other countries - toilet paper...) and there was no butter left for a few days. It is an unholy  abomination.

@WoJ If you go to Scandinavia and ask for butter in a random household, I’d say there’s about a 60% chance what you’ll get is a spreadable ‘butter’ made from a mixture of butter and oil. Many people (myself included) actually prefer them to real butter, not only for spreadability, but also for flavour. I can’t find any proper statistics, but some articles online indicate that in Denmark, margarine accounts for about 15% of fat-on-bread spreads, real butter about 34% and spreadable ‘butter’ about 51% – and no one would give you margarine if you ask for butter.

Whereas in Hungary, almost all baking is done with margarine (which is unsalted, same as butter), and if you ask for butter for your bread, you have even odds of getting butter or margarine.

@XanderHenderson I think you have a right to be annoyed if you ask for butter and someone brings you 'not butter' (and you can be sure that I can believe it is not butter.)

@JimmyJames: To be fair, "spreadable butter" is in fact butter, it just has canola oil (or possibly some other neutral vegetable oil) mixed in. Obviously not a great choice for baking, or in any circumstances where you really care what ingredients you're using, but it's entirely fine on toast.

@Kevin Oh, I know about spreadable butter but "I can't believe it's not butter" is not butter, as the name implies.

Typically, restaurants in the US that serve butter instead of margarine (a vanishing minority, it must be sadly said) serve salted butter. I suppose that might mean that salted butter is "normal." I personally prefer unsalted butter.
I grew up in a margarine family (horrible stuff) so I don't have any family precedent to draw on. Except, perhaps that my best friend's family used salted butter. I didn't realize that butter was ever salted until I tried unsalted butter when I was older.

I have this with breads: when I go to the US they taste really sweet to me.

@WoJ Probably because we put extra sugar in bread to hide the taste of the preservatives. Off-the-shelf bread in the US can sit for a couple of weeks before it will get mouldy. If it even does then. So it's probably full of chemicals.

The reason that culinary videos specify unsalted butter is that salt should be added to taste. Using salted butter may cause a cook to use too much salt since some salt is already present. Many people cannot have salt because they have blood pressure or heart disease issues. Unsalted butter allows the cook to omit salt entirely, or add only as much as necessary. Either unsalted butter is the "default" or there isn't one.

Thanks but this really does not answer my question at all. I am not asking about the differences or reasons for salter or unslated butter, but which one is the "normal" one in the US.

@WoJ I've edited the answer to address that directly.
